# Word interop problem : String parameter too long

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Im working on word app which is allowed me to change the text inside a word document but I get error String parameter too long because the text is more than 255 char . here is the code im using

```
        private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application wordApp, object ToFindText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllforms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
            ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
            ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
            ref replace, ref matchKashida,
            ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
            ref matchControl);

        
        var shapes = myWordDoc.Shapes;
        foreach (Word.Shape shape in shapes)
        {
            var initialText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
            var resultingText = initialText.Replace(Convert.ToString(ToFindText), Convert.ToString(replaceWithText));
            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
        }

    }
```

I get an error(string parameter too long)in this line

```
  wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
            ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
            ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
            ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
            ref replace, ref matchKashida,
            ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
            ref matchControl);
```

Comment: Which line causes the problem?

Comment: wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
                ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
                ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                ref matchControl);

Comment: Open Word, open the find and replace dialog, and try typing as much text as possible. The field is limited to 255 characters, so it's not surprising that the interop API has the same limitation as well

Comment: @Darwiesh See if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38456692/8967612) works for you. It seems like an exact duplicate.

Comment: @ 41686d6564 I tried it but for sorry not working

Comment: Try breaking your text up or using AuitoText rather than the text. You could replace the  found text with a bookmark and then insert your text into the bookmark. If the found text is too long, you could find the start if that is sufficient and extend the rangfe of the found text, delete it and replace it with the bookmark.